Why does find or ls boost rsync on an sshfs mount?
I faced something strange. A remote server is limited to SFTP, but I wanted to use rsync to transfer some files to it, so I used sshfs to mount the remote server to a local path:
! sshfs $USER@$HOST:/ "$MNT_DIR" -o IdentityFile=$idfile && echo "Error: Could not mount" && exit 1

After a successful transfer of 16k files I repeated my rsync command and wondered, why it took 90 seconds (as no new files were added I expected a really fast execution):
rsync -v --recursive --times --itemize-changes --exclude '*~' $LOCAL_DIR "$MNT_DIR"

After several tests, I found out that find -ls "$MNT_DIR" took only 1 second and by accident I executed find before rsync and now both in combination need only 1.1 second?!
find "$MNT_DIR" >/dev/null # 1 second
rsync -v --recursive --times --itemize-changes --exclude '*~' $LOCAL_DIR "$MNT_DIR" # 0.1 second

Even with ls it works as long the absolute path to the huge subdirectory is provided:
ls "$MNT_DIR/images" >/dev/null # 1 second
rsync -v --recursive --times --itemize-changes --exclude '*~' $LOCAL_DIR "$MNT_DIR" # 0.1 second

Finally I don't really understand what is happening here. At first I thought find and ls are able to fill the sshfs cache with metadata, while rsync is not, but as I don't use metadata options with the ls or find command, those data shouldn't be cached. Or is it simply the kind how rsync is obtaining the file list, which makes it so much slower in combination with an sshfs mount?
Used versions:
cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"

sshfs -V
SSHFS version 3.7.1
FUSE library version 3.10.5
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.31
fusermount3 version: 3.10.5

rsync -V
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31

find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0


try mounting with sshfs -o cache=no
